# Running a Java war file deployed on Tomcat over Windows server 2016 Docker container

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile, windows-server-2016, windows-container

Trying to run a Java .war file with Docker on Windows server 2016.

With Linux container it can be done by pulling Tomcat image (*which is built on top of openJDK and uses Debian as a base image*) and adding war file to *webapps* folder through **Dockerfile**.

But, Tomcat do not currently has any image for Windows containers, since openJDK too doesn't have support for **Microsoft/windowsservercore** or **Microsoft/nanoserver**

In my view, to be able to run war on Tomcat for windows We will need:

- windowsservercore
- JDK:JRE installation on top of windowsservercore
- Tomcat installation with Environment Vars of installed JDK.

To create the final image JDK is downloaded and installed through PS :

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM windowsservercore

RUN powershell (new-object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadfile('http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/Au toDL?BundleId=210185', 'C:\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe')
RUN powershell start-process -filepath C:\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe -passthru  -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=c:\Java\jre1.8.0_91,/L,install64.log"
RUN del C:\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe

CMD [ "c:\\Java\\jre1.8.0_91\\bin\\java.exe", "-version"]
```

But I am not sure how to install Tomcat with Environment variables set and then adding war to the webapps Directory.

Heard about *WinDocks*, but I would like to build without it.

Anyone has some insights on this?

Comment: It might be helpful to understand why you're trying to do that. Why can't you use the Debian-based Tomcat image?

Comment: No Debian based Tomcat image when pulled on Windows Containers, will throw "docker: image operating system "Linux" cannot be used on this platform."